# C# Tabless Control Previous/Back/Return Button failing?

Tags: c#

I am hoping someone here can help me, i have a Tabless Control on my windows forms application and basically because the tabs are purposely hidden i have added 2 buttons to each tab "Next" and "Back".

This is the code snippet i have for my "Next" button:

```
private void nextbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;
    this.toolStripStatusLabel8.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Which works fine, however when i use the exact same theory on the "Back" button it does not work:

```
private void backbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabmain;
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

So my question is how does one go to a previous tabpage from a button? I have looked through here and tried all of the links that came up but nothing has worked any ideas?

Comment: Is `tabmain` a TabPage? Or the tab control itself?

Comment: it is a TabPage the tabControl is: tabControl1

Comment: When you say "it does not work", are you getting an Exception, or is the tab control just not change? Does the ToolStrip Label update after clicking the back button?

Comment: The tab doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `SelectedIndex` property instead of using concrete `TabPage` instances. This way it will still work when you decide to change the order of the pab pages or add new pages:

```
private void previousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex--;
    }
}

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex < tabControl1.TabCount - 1)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex++;
    }
}
```

Since there is no "Tabless" tab control in .NET Framework I can only assume that it works similar to the standard [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx). If the solution doesn't work you should give us some information about the actual class you use.

BTW: There is no need to repeat the buttons on each page. Why don't you just put the buttons outside the TabControl?

Also: I see that you use a `ToolStripStatusLabel` to show the current time. Instead of updating it each time the user clicks somewhere add a `Timer` to your form. Set its `Interval` to 1000 and handle its `Tick` event. Update the label there:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

This way it updates constantly and again there is no need to repeat anything. You need to call `timer1.Start()` in the form's constructor.

Comment: Thankyou. Makes sence i am still clearly new to C# and thankyou for you help/time. It seems that the above works fine for going to the next tab but it still wont go "Back".

Comment: The class i use is this:

'using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class TablessControl : TabControl
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
        if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode) m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}'

I will use your timer method as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Burgo855: If this doesn't work for the "Back" button you can be sure that the `previousButton_Click` method is never called. Have a look at the button's `Click` event in the designer.

Comment: Strange, i removed the button and made a new one with the above formula for the event and it worked thanks heaps... +1